# Doesn't appear Android 5 in Eclipse's TargetSdk

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-5.0-lollipop, target-sdk

I have downloaded the last Android Api 21 using Sdk Manager, and I have deinstalled the L Preview.

This is the sdk's situation :
[image]

But when I go to open a new project in Eclipse, the last Android 5 doesn't appear in the options :

[image]

[image]

In the Eclipse's preferences this is the Android's settings :

[image]

Is it normal ? Why Android 5 doesn't appear ? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it's normal. It's just because with the latest update they didn't upgrade Eclipse (ADT). I think the Eclipse support is not the best now because Google is moving on Android Studio :(

Comment: Argh... Android studio is much slower then Eclipse on my PC :(